# Prime Faces p:commandButton stops sending actionListeners once disabled option is added

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

My `p:commandButton` stops sending `actionListeners` once I add `disabled` option. Why is this happening?

I have a `p:selectOneListbox` which needs to have something selected before `OK` button is enabled:

```
<p:selectOneListbox value="#{FileSelectBean.fileNameSelected}">  
  <f:selectItems value="#{FileSelectBean.fileNames}" />
  <p:ajax update=":formFileSelect:okId" />
</p:selectOneListbox>
```

And I have an `OK` button:

```
<p:commandButton id="okId" value="OK" 
    type="submit" update=":formEncryptionDialog" 
    actionListener="#{FileSelectBean.actionOk}" 
    oncomplete="dlgFileSelect.hide();"
    disabled="#{FileSelectBean.fileNameSelected.isEmpty()}">
</p:commandButton>
```

Backing bean:

```
private String fileNameSelected = "";
```

All works ok without `disabled="#{FileSelectBean.fileNameSelected.isEmpty()}"`. Once I add this, OK button is enabled/disabled properly, but stops calling `FileSelectBean.actionOk` after button is clicked.

What went wrong?

**Edit**:
I have removed `<p:ajax update=":formFileSelect:okId" />` and I refresh a button in some other way, but it did not help. So it seams not related to `ajax` in `selectOneListbox`.

Comment: Just a quick check- is it inside a form? Do you have nested forms? Did you try to set ajax="true" and ajax="false" and see if it changes anything? How do you update the button itself?

Comment: Try adding `process="@this :formFileSelect:okId" to the `p:ajax` tag.

Comment: It might have something to do with the timing of the update and the scope of your bean. ActionListeners fire before model updates so, depending on the scope of your bean, `#{FileSelectBean.fileNameSelected.isEmpty()}` might not have been updated in time to make a difference. Try changing the `actionListener` to `action`

Comment: Thanks but `action` did not help.

Comment: @jedrus07 Could you be more specific?

Comment: @Danijel I was wondering if you do not have nested forms anywhere, as this is common mistake. You have: disabled="#{FileSelectBean.fileNameSelected.isEmpty()}"> that works apparently. I wonder how are you updating the button itself to make it work? Also- FileSelectBean- what is the scope? Did you also tried to change the listener to:  actionListener="#{FileSelectBean.actionOk()}" Code of the listener could be helpful as well.

Comment: OK. No nested forms. I refresh the whole form to update the button after I removed the `ajax` line above. Bean is Request scoped unfortunatelly.

Comment: Listener code is not important since the call to `actionOk` is never done.

Comment: I had similar problem, once where the problem was the listener code- something not right with signature of the method. Also if you have inheritance it can be tricky. Can you just add the signature of the method to the question?

Comment: You mean this: `public void actionOk(){...}`?

Comment: The `#{FileSelectBean}` is in the view scope, right? See also point 5 of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked/2120183#2120183

Comment: No, it's Request scoped. Just tried View scoped and it didn't work.

Comment: Is the commandButton in the :formEncryptionDialog? And to debug add one h:outputText with an id and keep it's value as #{FileSelectBean.fileNameSelected.isEmpty()}. Put outputText id in selectOneMenu's update and checkout the output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<p:selectOneListbox id="primeOneListBox" value="#{FileSelectBean.fileNameSelected}">` 
     <f:selectItems value="#{FileSelectBean.fileNames}" />
     <p:ajax event="change" update=":formFileSelect:okId" process=":formFileSelect:primeOneListBox" />
</p:selectOneListbox>
```

And check if fileNameSelected setter method is called after selection